# Arabic footnotes in tcolorbox

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

If I use a `\footnote` command in `tcolorbox` the footnote will be alphabetically numbered. Question: How do I change this to arabic numbering?

I've tried `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}`, but that didn't work out. And the manual does not even mention the footnote changes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
    Some footnotes\footnote{Test} should be represented by an arabic number\footnote{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    Some footnotes\footnote{Test} should be represented by a letter\footnote{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that you posted a solution as well, just seconds in advance ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But well, I can accept your solution two days earlier and get 2 rep points now :)

Comment: Well, you could have accepted your solution anyway and get an upvote (at least from me) (Well, you got it anyway ;-))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usage of `\alph` instead of `\arabic` is no documented feature and only looking into `tcolorbox.sty` gives some insight about the proceedings in the package:

The counter used in `tcolorbox` boxes for footnotes is not `footnote` but `mpfootnote` (where `mp` is short for minipage) and `\thempfootnote` must be changed accordingly.

By default, in `latex.ltx`, `\thempfootnote` comes down to `\alph{mpfootnote}` effectively, i.e. using lower case letters for 'numbering' the footnotes, so the effect is the 'fault' of the LaTeX core itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
    Some footnotes\footnote{Test} should be represented by an arabic number\footnote{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    Some footnotes\footnote{Test} should be represented by a letter\footnote{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version with `code=` key and definition of a special box for arabic footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{footnotebox}[1][]{code={\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}},#1}


\begin{document}
\begin{footnotebox}
    Some footnotes\footnote{Test} are represented by an arabic number\footnote{Test}
\end{footnotebox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    Some footnotes\footnote{Test} should be represented by a letter\footnote{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```