# change footnote symbols to phaistos-hieroglf

Tags: footnotes, hieroglf, phaistos

Can I change footnote symbols with some symbols from `phaistos` or `hieroglf` package?

- I want to have only some of these symbols that I like,
- The change has to be at the entire document (main text, `minipage`, `tikz`-boxes, `tcolorbox`...)

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78227/184389

Comment: Thank's! It's almost done. I only have problems with `phaistos` symbols. There are not printed as symbols, but as "FF", "BB", "cc"...

Comment: @KersouMan , also it has problems in `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @KersouMan , I find the solution for `tcolorbox` using this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376682/arabic-footnotes-in-tcolorbox

Answer (score 1):

Phaistos Disc symbols, Egyptian Hieroglyphs, Linear B and so on, are now also available in unicode fonts, so a `fontspec` + xelatex/lualatex generic solution is possible, without need of `phaistos` or `hieroglf` packages. (Plus also, direct input with utf-8 encoding.)

[image: footnote symbols]
[image: footnotes]

Adapting the MWE by @Henrique at [Changing footnote symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols/78227#78227)

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fphaistos{Noto Sans Symbols}
\newfontface\flinearb{Noto Sans Linear B}
\newfontface\fegyhier{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}
\newcommand\myfna{{\fphaistos }}
\newcommand\myfnb{{\fphaistos }}
\newcommand\myfnc{{\fphaistos }}
\newcommand\myfnd{{\fphaistos }}
\newcommand\myfne{{\fphaistos }}
\newcommand\myfnf{{\fphaistos }}
\newcommand\myfng{{\flinearb }}
\newcommand\myfnh{{\fegyhier }}

\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols{myfnsymbols}{% def. from footmisc.sty
  \myfna
  \myfnb
  \myfnc
  \myfnd
  \myfne
  \myfnf
  \myfng
  \myfnh
}%
\setfnsymbol{myfnsymbols}
\begin{document}
text\footnote{a} text\footnote{b} text\footnote{c}
text\footnote{d} text\footnote{e} text\footnote{f}
text\footnote{g} text\footnote{h}
\end{document}
```

There is now a potential for the footnote marks to carry semantic meaning: `see`, background history, current issues, developments, related matters, curiosa, and so on. Perhaps as hyperlinks to a wiki structure (in turn, that would make bot-crawling easier when building up a semantic web).

And, with a multiplicity of icons, there is also now even more incentive to use footnotes sparingly, in order not to overburden the reader's cognitive load with TLDR.